# How to use Form_submit hook?

Tags: 7, hooks, forms

I have a form, automatically generated by a content type. I want to run a form_submit function to input/change some data to get saved in the database.

The content-type already has these fields setup, but I want them to be determined in a form_submit function rather than via user input.

I can get a form submit function, but I don't know how to add to the array of values being submitted without having to write the whole query myself.  What variables do I need to grab and how to alter them to do this?

To be more specific.. in the form_alter, this does what I want. `$form["field_org_id"]["und"][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $org->id;`

But how do I do the equivalent out of site in the form_submit? (this is a content-add form and hoping not to rewrite the entire query)

Answer (score 25):

1. You have to use [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) or [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7)
2. Add your submit handler to [$form['#submit']](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#submit_property) like this `$form['#submit'][]='my_submit'`
3. And write your code:

   ```
   function my_submit($form, &$form_state) { 
     // your code
   }
   ```

Comment: isn't there an auto generated form_submit hook name? I was trying that but wasn't working

Comment: this is taken from (http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#submit_property) **Description:**  A list of custom submit functions that will be called when the element is submitted. This is usually to add additional submit functions to a form, or to use an alternate function rather than the default form validation function which is the form ID with _submit appended to it.

Comment: ok i have the hook working either though none of the ways that are supposed to work were working. But my real concern is how to write the function itself.. if I have `$form["field_org_id"]["und"][0]['value']['#default_value'] = $org->id;` in my form_alter.. how would I implement that same effect in my form_submit

Comment: it seems like you are working with `node_submit` for this have a look at [hook_node_submit](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_submit/7)

Answer (score 3):

The FORM_FUNCTION_submit() function fires automatically when the form with the prefix generator function is submitted:

```
function generate_special_form(){ // this function name is "FORM_FUNCTION" above
    $form = array();
    $form['field_org_id'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => 'Organisation',
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'Submit',
    );
    return $form;
}
```

When that function submits it will automatically call the function generate_special_form_submit() with 2 parameters, you can get the submitted values like this:

```
function generate_special_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
    // Form above was submitted, now lets clean up $form_state['values'], 
    // that's the submitted values in an associative array.
    form_state_values_clean($form_state);
    // And here is the value that was submitted:
    drupal_set_message($form_state['values']['field_org_id']);
}
```

It looks like you're trying to modify a form that is generated in core. If that's the case, use hook_form_alter to add the $form['#submit'] value as Jibran outline above.